# Accidentally removed privileges from root user and can't access database

Tags: mysql, permissions

New to databases and accidentally removed privileges from root user; only privileges I currently have are USAGE and PROXY. This is a MySQL database that I access through HeidiSQL. Currently cannot access my data tables; is there a way to get these privileges restored? Did not create any other user accounts.